# Объясните где ошибка!

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста, вылезает ошибка:

> java: variable x might not have been initialized

```
public boolean question(){
    System.out.print("Еще карту? ");
    boolean x;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = input.nextLine();

    if (input.nextLine() == "Да" || input.nextLine() == "да"){
        x = true;
    } else if (input.nextLine() == "Нет" || input.nextLine() == "нет"){
        x = false;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Нет такой команды. Напишите: Да или Нет ");
        question();
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в том, что на момент возвращения переменной `x` из метода ей может быть не присвоено значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор вам говорит о том, что значение `x` может быть неопределено. Действительно, если пользователь введет `123` чему оно будет равно?

А вообще в методе куча ошибок. Например, эта строка

```
(input.nextLine() == "Да" || input.nextLine() == "да")
```

приведет к двойному чтению данных.

А сравнивать строки через `==` это вообще нонсенс.

Про неадекватную рекурсию я вообще молчу.

Вот рабочий метод

```
public boolean question(){
    System.out.print("Еще карту? ");
    int x = -1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        String answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (answer.equals("да") {
            x = 1;
        } else if (answer.equals("нет")) {
            x = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Нет такой команды. Напишите: Да или Нет ");
        }
    } while (x == -1);
    return x == 1;
}
```

Comment: Учу Java неделю и поэтому про нонсансы не в курсе ещё. А если пользователь введёт Да или Нет в вашем варианте, то это не приведёт к повторному чтению данных? Спасибо за исправления!

Comment: @SopaEspesa Нет. Т.к. метод `nextLine()` вызывается только один раз

Comment: Как тогда правильно сделать, чтобы ответ был Да или да и Нет или нет?

Comment: @SopaEspesa Так я уже сделал. Введенный ответ пользователя приводится к нижнему регистру `answer = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();`, а затем сравнивается с `да` и `нет`. Если был введен один из этих ответов то происходит выход из процедуры. Нет - ожидается ответ еще раз

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо инициализировать в методе переменную **x**.
Задай ей по умолчанию значение:

```
boolean x = false;
```